# Log additional properties apart from response in a .net core api in a cross-cutting way

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, logging, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an API in .NET 6 say "WrapperAPI" which calls a third party API say "ExternalAPI". The "ExternalAPI" returns response in below format -

```
{
   prop1: "",
   prop2: ""
}
```

I then return "prop1" from "WrapperAPI" endpoints as response. I want to log "prop2" in a database.

This format is common for most/all endpoints in my API. How can I log "prop2" from all endpoints in my API in a cross cutting way?

I know a middleware allows us to handle cross-cutting concerns like logging at a global level for all endpoints, but "prop2" is not a part of my Response JSON.

Also I want this logging to be asynchronous if possible.

Comment: What about adding it to httpcontext.items  and handling it in middleware?